# How to change the Publisher of a model driven app in D365

Tags: dynamics-365, power-platform, model-driven-app

I'm new to Power Platform and still learning how to do certain things.
I have a model driven app, and the D365 App page shows it is registered under the **Default Publisher**. See below.

[image]

Is there a way I can change this to use my own publisher? I have already created my own publisher.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can change it after you've created the mda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Just Do It](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067286/just-do-it) mentioned, it cannot be changed. However as long as we have specified the Custom Publisher Name when creating the Model Driven App (which I have), and we exported it out (as Managed, not sure about UnManaged), to the target environment (i.e Test) Portal shows the correct publisher for the Model Driven App.

There is also similar question being asked [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/146783/how-to-change-the-publisher-of-a-solution?pifragment-97030=1).